# Spring security or custom?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have three types of user(role)SuperAdmin, Admin, CS, XYZ. Multiple roles can  be assigned to any user.

Now I am mapping all the actions in a table.
Then on each action I am authorizing the user. All this is custom.
Even though I do not find any difficulty and everything is dynamic.
I doubt if this is the better way or spring provides this out of the box?

Please suggest

Comment: Please post your current code in order to allow us to understand what you are doing.

Comment: spring security approach would provide this out of the box, people will answer question based on what you have tried, (not for opinions)

Comment: In general: security is a complex matter, and there is a multitude of corner cases that you need to keep track of. Trying to implement this yourself is typically a bad idea.